# Unable to connect to remote server when hitting an API -RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have created one console application and published it as well. when I run the exe on my local machine it works fine but whenever I try to run the .exe on server which I have copied along with the required DLLS it gives the following response:

```
status code as 0
Unable to connect to remote server
```

Application tries to hit the API url (https://XXX-uat.YYY.AAA.com:993) from the server web01.r.prd.glXXal gives the above error .

does proxy/firewall is stopping the API call ? I am not sure if this is the issue, how to check it?

Comment: Easiest way to see if you can reach the website from the server is to `ping` it, ssh (or whatever) into your server and run `ping https://XXX-uat.YYY.AAA.com`, if you're not getting a reply then something is wrong with the routing, you can try and get to the bottom of that using `tracert` and seeing where your ping attempt dies

Comment: @MindSwipe I tried ping XXX-uat.YYY.AAA.com , I get all sent packets received 0 % loss. does this mean proxy is not an issue here but port 993 is blocked by firewall ?

Comment: For that you can use `netcat` do `nc -vz XXX-uat.YYY.AAA.com 993`